# Protect Generated PDF from changes

Tags: java, pdf, itext, digital-signature, sha256

I need your help in securing the generated PDF from the method from any unexpected changes and tampers as I will be adding at the bottom of the generated PDFs,the image of the manager's signature. The application in located under a secured website (Https) and encryption and decryption is implemented in it. Only authorized users will be accessing the application and they will download different generated PDFs. I got a requirement to secure the PDF, where in my current code I am generating the PDF only. Similar sample code is below for generating the PDF similar to my code:

```
public void GeneratedPDF {
    Document document = new Document();

    try {
        PdfWriter.getInstance(document,
            new FileOutputStream("CE.pdf"));

        document.open();
        document.add(new Paragraph("Secured Document"));
        document.close(); 

    } catch (DocumentException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

I thought to add:

```
document.addTitle("CE");
document.addAuthor("XYZ Company");
document.addSubject("TCE");
document.addKeywords(CE");
document.addCreator("XYZ Company");
```

I was given a suggestion to implement the SHA256 security, but still I am not sure whether it is beneficial to implement or not. So can you please assist?

Comment: What kind of security do you want? If someone can view the PDF contents, he can manipulate them if he knows a bit about PDFs or PDF processing software, so regular password protection is not what you're looking for. Do you want to add a digital signature which would be invalidated by such manipulation? Or are you looking for some proprietary DRM solution?

Comment: @mkl I need the easiest way to either implement a digital signature to show that this PDF is downloaded from our website and it is trusted or I need to make sure that the size of the PDF file and its content wasn't changed and no one has changed them after calling the method. In simple words I want to make sure that no changes were done to the file and the PDF is trusted

Comment: Is it possible to inform the recipients what to look for to check whether the file is tampered? In that case a digital signature indeed can be used for this. Otherwise I don't see a way.